# Несколько вопросов про std::fstream

Tags: c++, ооп, fstream

Класс `fstream` наследуется от `istream` и `ostream` и ещё от других классов. В классе `istream` определён метод `seekg`, а в `ostream` - `seekp`. Так же и с функциями `tellg` и `tellp`.

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно при записи использовать функции `seekp` и `tellp`, а при чтении из файла - `seekg` и `tellg`?
2. Стоит ли объекту типа `std::fstream` при открытии передавать `openmode` (`std::ios_base::in` или `std::ios_base::out`) при чтении и записи соответственно и использовать соответствующие функции из классов `istream` при `std::ios_base::in` и наоборот?
3. И почему, если у объекта типа `std::fstream` вызвать метод `open()` и передать в аргумент `std::ios_base::in`, метод `seekp`, унаследованный от класса `ostream` будет работать корректно, хотя мы указали, что мы собираемся читать из файла, а не выводить в него?
   Заранее спасибо.

Comment: не важно какой функцией вы установили позицию `seekp` или `seekg`. В файловом буфере позиция одна. Зачем сделали две функции не знаю. До сих пор. В Си пока нет двух названий. Есть только `fseek` и `ftell`.

Comment: Вероятно просто универсальный интерфейс. В `std::stringstream` два индикатора позиции и их можно изменять независимо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс  `std::fstream`  это псевдоним класса  `std::basic_fstream<char, char_traits<char>>`, который является наследником `std::basic_iostream<char, char_traits<char>>`, то есть `std::iostream`. А это значит, что для  `std::fstream` "папа"  `std::iostream`, а `istream` и `ostream` это  родители последнего, а значит для `std::fstream` являются только "дедушка" с "бабушкой". Это маленькая поправка к вашей информации.

1. Все верно, для записи используются одни, а для чтения другие
   функции_члены.
2. Так как  объект типа `std::fstream`  умеет(имеет такое наследство) и
   записывать и читать, то по умолчанию  он так и делает. Но если
   хотите, чтобы он только записывал или только читал, то нужно
   установить соответствующий  режим, но тогда пропадает смысл его
   использования, а не использования прямого другого наследника
   `istream` и `ostream`, то есть `std::ifstream`  и   `std::ofstream`.
3. От всего выше сказанного следует, что, если вы имеете *объект
   std::fstream*, а значит вы имеете объект с возможностью для чтения и
   записи из файла/в файл, а следовательно Вы можете с его помощью
   открыть файл в любом режиме. Но это не влияет  на его
   функциональность, он как умел  изменять положение выходного потока (
   seekp) , так и будет уметь, но только установленный режим может не
   дасть записывать туда что то

Comment: `Вы можете с его помощью открыть файл в любом режиме. Но это не влияет на его функциональность` Не очень понятно, почему это так. Что мешает, например, функции `seekp()` проверять, в подходящем ли режиме открыт файл? И если нет, то, например, генерировать исключение. Или что ещё хуже, может при неправильном использовании потока поведение вообще не определено?

Comment: Я думаю, что сам тип позиции в файле одинаковый что для записи и для чтения, поэтому работает как и seekp, так и seekg, поэтому, даже если указать что будет происходить запись, `seekg()` сработает корректно, но вот считать уже что-то не выйдет. А если не указывать `openmode`, то сработает как и запись, так и чтение. От ответа понял, что `std::fstream` это своего рода обобщение `std::ostream` и `std:istream` и, может, был создан, чтобы кода плодить меньше.

Comment: @mld8nk,  обобщение  `std::ofstream` и `std:ifstream`, которые не являются обобщением std::ostream и std:istream (больше подходит "расширение"). И любой класс существует  (в том числе и std::fstream), как часть принципа объектно ориентированного программирования, а это далеко не только   для того,  чтобы кода плодить меньше...